# WKWebView Leaks

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, webkit, wkwebview

Profiling my app, I noticed a couple of leaks.

## Memory Issues - (2 leaked types)

- 1 instance of *OS_dispatch_source* leaked
- 3 instances of

`std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<std::__1::mutex, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::mutex> >`  leaked

---

### OS_dispatch_source

Description:

> `<OS_dispatch_source: source[0x2801d1500] = { xref = 1, ref = 2, target = WebKit Malloc Memory Pressure Handler[0x2801d1f00], ident = 0x0, mask = 0x4, pending_data = 0x0, registered = 1, armed = 1, kevent = 0x280cd5450 (direct), filter = memorystatus }>`

Located under:

> libdispatch.dylib

Notes:
Only is present sometimes, and it appears to only ever have 1 object leaking.

---

### std::__1::shared_ptr_emplace......

Description:

> No Description available

Located under:

> JavaScriptCore

Seems to always be present with at least 2 leaks.

---

I am using WebKit's WKWebView which is clearly related, but I don't really know what my next step is.  I've searched online, and have read about other webkit leaks, but I haven't really found anything particular about these 2.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm having the same exacts leaks but I'm not using WKWebView. My app uses Google SDK and does some file downloads with URLSessionsDataTask

Comment: No unfortunately I haven’t  found anything else regarding this. Which google api is it, Firebase?

Comment: I'm only getting this leak when starting up the app from scratch and tapping on the Sign In button (which then opens up the web view ) so my guess is that this leak is caused by the Google Sign-In SDK.